# Getting error while calling resources from resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have attached the resource file , and when I debugging the code the below error generates.
Is it the way to call resources or any other way to do this?

```
 RegularExpressionValidator1.ErrorMessage = App_GlobalResources.ManageJobs.ResourceManager.GetString("SpecialCharectersValidationMessage");
```

> *Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture. Make sure
>   "Zerk.Website.App_GlobalResources.ManageJobs.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "Zerk.Website" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.*

Can any one help me on this ???????

Comment: Can any one help me on this ???????

Comment: Have you validated the spelling? Character != Charecter. Also you should check if the file is there and the Build Action within Visual Studio is set to "Embedded Resource".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got success with following code.

```
<%$ Resources:ManageJobs,NameOfResource %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the resource using:

Resources.ManageJobs.SpecialCharectersValidationMessage

Make sure file ManageJobs.resx has Compile Action set to Content and Custom tool set to GlobalResourceProxyGenerator.

Comment: I am not able to access Resources.ManageJobs.SpecialCharectersValidationMessage, but other Actions are correct.

Comment: When you type "Resources.ManageJobs." inside VS editor do the Intellisense shows you (in the dropdown) the resources IDs that are inside your resource file or not?